Dynamic Table Filtering and Aggregation with Percentage-Based Display Conditions in SNOWFLAKE
I'm looking for a solution to fulfill the following requirements for a table query.
With a SELECT on a table, the table is to be filtered and aggregated as required. The percentage of available information per company is calculated from the result and ranked. This calculation is then used to decide whether values are displayed or not.
When a new request is made, the percentage values should be recalculated and the decision to display the data should be made again.
Example:
The condition for displaying values is that the two largest companies have a maximum of 80% of the filtered data set.

Query: SELECT * FROM employees WHERE company_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
(Calculated percentage of each company_id = 59%, 21%, 20%)
Result: Values are displayed.

Query: SELECT * FROM employees WHERE company_id = 3;
(Calculated percentage of company_id = 100%)
Result: No values are displayed.


I have tried to solve this via the policies, UDFs, stored procedures or recursive CTEs, unfortunately without success.
What solution is there to generate such a dynamic query?
Does anyone have an idea to resolve this problem?

ok some fake data so we can agree how this is working using a CTE, with both runs mixed together to make it the simplest for me:
with fake_data(run, company_id, value, filter) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 10, 39, true),
    (1, 10, 20, true),
    (1, 11, 20, true),
    (1, 11, 1, true),
    (1, 12, 10, true),
    (1, 12, 10, true),
    (1, 13, 1000, false),
    (2, 20, 90, true),
    (2, 20, 10, true)
)

then we can do the filtering:
select * 
from fake_data as f
where f.filter = true;


now to agreegate those values:
select run,
    company_id,
    sum(value) as s_val
from fake_data as f
where f.filter = true
group by 1,2 
order by 1,2;


Now to use ratio_to_report to do the percentages:
select run,
    company_id,
    sum(value) as s_val,
    ratio_to_report(s_val) over (partition by run) as ra
from fake_data as f
where f.filter = true
group by 1,2 
order by 1,2;

which given the way you have shown the results, the sum(value) can be moved into the ratio thus:
ratio_to_report(sum(value)) over (partition by run) as ra


now we want to rank those companies inside the run:
select *,
    row_number() over (partition by run order by ra desc) as rank,   
from (
    select run,
        company_id,
        ratio_to_report(sum(value)) over (partition by run) as ra
    from fake_data as f
    where f.filter = true
    group by 1,2 
)
order by 1,2;


then we want to sum the 1st and 2nd
select *,
    row_number() over (partition by run order by ra desc) as rank,   
    lead(ra) over (partition by run order by ra desc) as lead_ra,
    iff(rank = 1, ra + zeroifnull(lead_ra), null) as first_sum
from (
    select run,
        company_id,
        ratio_to_report(sum(value)) over (partition by run) as ra
    from fake_data as f
    where f.filter = true
    group by 1,2 
)
order by 1,2;


Now we want to pull that first_sum across all values of the same set:
select *,
    lead(first_sum, 1, first_sum) ignore nulls over (partition by run order by ra) as run_total
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by run order by ra desc) as rank,   
        lead(ra) over (partition by run order by ra desc) as lead_ra,
        iff(rank = 1, ra + zeroifnull(lead_ra), null) as first_sum
    from (
        select run,
            company_id,
            ratio_to_report(sum(value)) over (partition by run) as ra
        from fake_data as f
        where f.filter = true
        group by 1,2 
    )
)
order by 1,2;


now to filter the runs to only show those values that meet the threshold set.
select *,
    lead(first_sum, 1, first_sum) ignore nulls over (partition by run order by ra) as run_total
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by run order by ra desc) as rank,   
        lead(ra) over (partition by run order by ra desc) as lead_ra,
        iff(rank = 1, ra + zeroifnull(lead_ra), null) as first_sum
    from (
        select run,
            company_id,
            ratio_to_report(sum(value)) over (partition by run) as ra
        from fake_data as f
        where f.filter = true
        group by 1,2 
    )
)
qualify run_total <= 0.8
order by 1,2;


now the whole thing can be tidied up, to carry just the results needed at each step and any other formating fun you want.
